# Axios giving error on get request in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, api, axios

I have been trying to get data from the api using axios get request but it keeps on giving me error. The error is TypeError: this.setstate is not a function i have seen multiple queries about it and almost all of them had done it this way but i cant figure out what iam doing wrong.

My code for axios get

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

class Questionare extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  
          items: [],

    }
} 

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('http://leaty-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/services/app/PersonalityQuestionerCategory/GetAllPersonalityQuestionerCategory')
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setstate({items: response.data})
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

    render() { 

       return (
          <ul>
            {this.state.items.map(item=>(
             <li>{item.pqcDetail}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
       )
    }

}

export default Questionare;
```

Comment: I suggest converting response to json by `response.json()`

Comment: My mistke has been corrected it was camel case mistake but i have another error         TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's camel case `setState()` not `setstate()`

corrected

```
this.setState({items: response.data})
```

Improved complete code ---Live https://74u3w.csb.app/

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class Questionare extends Component {
  state = {
      items: []
    };
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://leaty-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/services/app/PersonalityQuestionerCategory/GetAllPersonalityQuestionerCategory"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ items: response.data.result.items });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => (
          <li>{item.pqcDetail}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked but i have another problem

Comment: TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function

Comment: @AbdulRauf can you show your json response data sample?. is it array or object

Comment: its an array of 7 items

Comment: {data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
data:
result:
items: Array(7)
0: {pqcDetail: "WHEN INVOLVED IN A PROJECT WITH OTHER PEOPLE", isActive: true}
1: {pqcDetail: "IN SEEKING SATISFACTION THROUGH MY WORK", isActive: true}
2: {pqcDetail: "WHEN THE TEAM IS TRYING TO SOLVE A PARTICULARLY COMPLEX PROBLEM", isActive: true}
3: {pqcDetail: "IN CARRYING OUT MY DAY-TO-DAY WORK", isActive: true}
4: {pqcDetail: "IF I AM SUDDENLY GIVEN A DIFFICULT TASK WITH LIMITED TIME AND UNFAMILIAR PEOPLE", isActive: true}

Comment: @AbdulRauf if answer is helpful for you please accept/vote for this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. @VahidAkhtar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205726/discussion-between-abdul-rauf-and-vahid-akhtar).